Judge, tall bench, defendant standing, ruling handed down, electric chair appears, defendant is dragged and immediately killed
I need help figuring out the movie or TV show in which the following is a part of. I only remember a small scene of it; this was a long time ago (maybe even 10+ or 15+ years ago, but should be a release of after 1995).
I remember blue lighting in a courtroom. A woman was the judge with a white wig. A defendant in a tank top and shorts and arguing with the judge and at some point spotlight shows an electric chair being unveiled behind him.
The judge's bench was significantly elevated as the defendant had to argue looking up. Then the defendant turns back and sees it and starts to describe his work history and how long he's been a part of some organization, but he's quickly interrupted by the judge as she yells "silence" and a then two men cloaked head to toe with something making them look like boogie-men and dragged the defendant to the electric chair and killed him.
While the man was being electrocuted the camera cuts to the disappointed looks of some people watching from some luxury looking rooms with hands to their forehead and the judge gave the occasional side-eye while continuing to write on her bench watching the execution.
It was definitely not a black and white movie. The electric chair was inside the courtroom behind the people who were there. The scene was extremely dark apart from the men from luxury rooms who were watching disappointed; it also had a serious tone.

While highly fictional I'm not seeing any Science Fiction or Fantasy elements here,

does it have to be science? It's definitely fantasy. Executed immediately after death order. I still need help finding this tho.

@Paulie_D this has a decent chance of being from some series that is in scope. Consider the very similar The Twilight Zone: The Obsolete Man

Definitely not black and white. The judge's bench was lit up in green shish blue lighting. This electric chair was so simple I wouldn't be able to distinguish it from patio furniture (but small, metal and with circular holes). And the courtroom was dark!!!! Like NO windows! At all! That's why they needed a (same blueish) spotlight for the electric chair because the back of the courtroom was pitch black.

I'm beginning to think this is likely an episode of some TV show as none of my searches into movies are going anywhere.

ALSO, I'm not entire sure if they spoke English; I could have just remember reading the subtitles LOL. Sorry, that sounds like critical information.
